# I won’t be very late tonight, I shouldn’t imagine (so)

Tags: grammaticality, ellipsis

> [*I won’t be very late tonight, I shouldn’t imagine (**so**).*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/negation-two-negatives)

Is it grammatically correct to add **so** here? why?

Comment: Don't add 'so' in a statement. You can use it in an answer, e.g. Q. Will you be late tonight?  A. I shouldn't imagine so.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey why?

Comment: 'So' refers back to something previously said. Check a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

We use 'so' to avoid repeating something asked or mentioned in an earlier sentence. It would not be correct to add it to a simple sentence like 'I won’t be very late tonight, I shouldn’t imagine'.

It could be used in an answer to a question:
*Will you be late tonight? I shouldn't imagine so

Will it rain tomorrow? I don't think so.*

> So
> used to say that a situation mentioned earlier is correct or true
>
> *"Is it true that we're not getting a pay increase this year?" "I'm afraid so."*

[So (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so)

Answer (score 1):

Person 1: Does he want to go tonight?
Person 2: I wouldn't or shouldn't imagine so.

COMPARE

A simple statement to someone: I won't be late tonight, I wouldn't/shouldn't imagine.

No so.

*So* refers to a preceding utterance.